# Meteor: Unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I'm getting the following error on my meteor app (using meteor-boilerplate)

```
server/startup/loadPlugins.js:12:3: Unexpected token }
```

This is the code:

```
  1 Meteor.startup(function () {
  2
  3   //load plugins
  4   if(Plugins.find().count() === 0) {
  5     var plugins = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('plugins.json'));
  6     _.each(plugins, (function () {
  7       plugins.insert({
  8         plugin_name: data
  9       });
 10       console.log('added plugin record');
 11     })
 12   }
 13
 14 }
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I have another file `models/plugins.js` which creates the collection:

```
plugins = new Mongo.Collection('plugins');
```

Comment: Also, using Meteor 1.0

Comment: You seem to be missing 2 times ")" on line 12 and 14

Comment: Actually, only on line 14... line 12 doesn't need one.

Comment: fixed working now -- post answer and i'll accept. feel like an idiot now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {

  //load plugins
  if(Plugins.find().count() === 0) {
    var plugins = JSON.parse(Assets.getText('plugins.json'));
    _.each(plugins, (function () {
      plugins.insert({
        plugin_name: data
      });
      console.log('added plugin record');
    }));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `_.each` isn't closed properly.